# Create auto-numbering on images/figures in MS Word

Tags: image, ms-word, document

I have MS Word document which contains around 50 images with caption.

My problem is if I am inserting images in between (say inserting image after image 21) then the image is not taking the caption on its own(new image must be inserted with caption 22).

I need to manually update number for all the images after the newly added image. Can I automate it?

Comment: which version of MS Word do you use?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I assume you are using the caption feature of Word, that is, captions were not typed in as normal text, but were inserted using *Insert > Caption* (Word versions before 2007), or *References > Insert Caption* (in the ribbon of Word 2007 and up). If done correctly, the captions are really 'fields'. You'll know if it is a field if the caption's background turns grey when you put your cursor on them (or is permanently displayed grey).

**Captions are fields** -  Unfortunately fields (like caption fields) are only updated on specific actions, like opening of the document, printing, switching from print view to normal view, etc. The easiest way to force updating of all (caption) fields when you want it is by doing the following:

1. Select all text in your document (easiest way is to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>)
2. Press <kbd>F9</kbd>, this command tells Word to update all fields in the selection.

**Captions are normal text** - If the caption number is not a field, I am afraid you'll have to edit the text manually.

Comment: I have tried this option earlier. But what i want is whenever i add any image the caption must come with the sequence. currently i have manually go to image, right click and then add caption.

Comment: Ah, indeed. That was not clear to me from your question (maybe edit it?). To work around the issue you are describing, I always copy an existing image and caption to a new location. I just have to replace the image with the correct one (and change the caption text). That saves me from doing Insert > Caption and selecting the appropriate caption tag.

Comment: i dont think microsoft is smart enough to add and auto update caption when new image is added. Anyways followed the same insert caption approach

Comment: This doesn't work if the captions are in text boxes

Comment: @Paul: I am not sure /what/ doesn't work when inside text boxes, but then again, I try to avoid text boxes as much as possible.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if the captions are in text boxes. If you hit CTRL-A then F9, it won't update the field codes/numbers. It took me some time to figure this out. Putting them in text boxes is nice in a small document because you can group them and they'll float together, and I like top and bottom wrapping. But in a large document it's really not an option because of this issue, so you need to use paragraph settings to keep the captions with their content.

Comment: @Paul: Tried it in Windows 2007, and indeed the field in the text box doesn't get updated when doing CTRL-A F9. However, the fields after the text box are correctly numbered (i.e, they take the text box field into account for increasing their number). If you want to update *all* captions, doing a Print Preview worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

- Select whole document (Ctrl+A)
- Press F9
- Save

Should update the figure caption automatically.

My question is tho, how can one also 'assign' referenced figures '(Fig.4)' in the text to do the same thing - aka change when an image is added above it?

EDIT:
Figured it out.. In word go to **Insert** and **Cross-ref** and assign the ref. Then **Ctrl+A** and **F9** and everything should sort itself out.

Comment: Cross-referencing is a very good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Office 2007

Right click the figure, 
select Insert Caption, 
Select Numbering, 
check box next to 
'Include chapter number', 
select OK, 
Select OK again, 
then you figure identifier should be updated.